# indent_space for makeindex doesn't have any effect

Tags: indentation, indexing

I use the package `makeidx` which works fine. When I try to format the index with `file.ist` I have a problem, as the options `indent_space` and `indent_length` don't have any effect at all. `item_0` works fine nevertheless.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Would you mind adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! As far as I know, `indent_space` is used for indenting lines in the produced `.ind` file, but it has no effect for the final typesetting. What precisely do you want to achieve?

Comment: What does it help to format the .ind file?
I just want to reduce the indention in the final index.

Comment: You could use the package [idxlayout](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/idxlayout) to format the index.

Comment: @TinaGiesler MakeIndex does nothing regarding the spacing parameters in the typeset index; for instance, `item_0` default is to break a line in the `.ind` file and add `\item` in front of the entry; how `\item` is interpreted by LaTeX doesn't concern MakeIndex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As user21511 has commented, use my [`idxlayout`](http://ctan.org/pkg/idxlayout) package to tinker with the indentation of index entries and (sub)subentries. The most relevant package options (see the manual for details) are `indentunit`, `hangindent`, `subindent` and `subsubindent`, also have a look at `itemlayout`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage[unbalanced,indentunit=0.75em]{idxlayout}

\begin{document}

Some text.\index{An index entry long enough to cause a line break}%
    \index{An index entry long enough to cause a line break!A subentry}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]